# Guarantee email never goes to junk—Gmail / Google Apps for Business

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

We use Google Apps for Business to run our emails (Gmail) and we have quite a few emails that we get from the same people / the same address (@company.com) / or same subject, that always seem to go straight to junk.

I’ve tried adding these people as contacts, in Google Contacts, and also set a Gmail filter, to *Never send it to Spam*, *Mark it as important*, but sometimes they still go to the junk.

Any idea how I can 100% guarantee an email doesn’t go into the junk?

Answer (score 1):

The sender's domain may have incorrectly configured SPF or DKIM records. Google checks these and honors them. If the sender is a Google Apps domain, you are in luck and can send them these:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174124

If you take one of the messages that went into spam, [do "Show Original"](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en) and paste here: http://www.mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx you will be able to look at the anti-spam headers of the email that was sent.

Fail is likely a problem but neutral could be a problem too.